# Cannot launch ANY process in Java (ProcessBuilder process immediately returns with exit code 128)

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to have Java execute another program, and it kept immediately erroring out with exit code 128 and nothing sent to stdout or stderr.  I tried a simple "java -version" still with no luck.  When I run it in a cmd window, it runs fine and this code works on similarly configured other machines (Windows Server 2003 x64, Java 1.6 update 25)

**When run on command line:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\zugwalt>java -version
```

**Output:**

```
java version "1.6.0_25" Java(TM) SE
Runtime Environment (build1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Then I try this code:**

```
try {
            List<String> cmd = new LinkedList<String>();
            cmd.add("java");
            cmd.add("-version");
            ProcessBuilder apb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            apb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            System.out.println("STARTING w00t!");
            Process p = apb.start();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null; 
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("OUTPUT: "+line);
            }
            System.out.println("EXIT: "+p.exitValue());
            System.out.println("WAIT FOR: "+p.waitFor());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("CAUGHT: "+ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output is:**

```
STARTING w00t!  
EXIT: 128  
WAIT FOR: 128
```

Comment: More details (and focus) on the specific architecture/environment posted to ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/270657/java-subprocess-running-from-iis6-returns-exit-value-128-and-no-stdout-stderr

Comment: It's particularly interesting (and frustrating) that the Process object (p) is not null and that no exceptions are thrown, even though the underlying OS process (java.exe) doesn't appear to be launched successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we "solved" this by killing a large number of the system processes.  We think the problem is closely related to the issues described here: http://www.arcanadev.com/support/kb/K00000329.aspx, with the process trying to call java's exec being out of available heap space or memory.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `p.waitFor()` before `p.exitValue()`.

Comment: Calling p.waitFor() without p.exitValue() also produces 128.

Comment: I actually wasn't calling p.exitValue() at all and having the same problem. I just added in p.exitValue() to help give additional context (program not even starting)