# Is there a 1000 character limit somewhere from Tomcat calling Windows bat file?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, batch-file

I have a Tomcat servlet that is calling a Windows BAT file via java's ProcessBuilder.  Seems that if I have more than 1000 characters on a command within the BAT file then the process fails with a return code 128 back from ProcessBuilder.

Its very strange - I can edit the BAT file and put a few spaces in the offending command and cause the error...or I can remove the spaces and everything runs cleanly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6037336/102937

Comment: The limit for XP is 2048 characters: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Comment: @paulsm4: Erm.. The article you linked specifies Windows 2000 or Windows NT 4.0 for a limit of 2047 characters.  The limit in XP is 8191 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are much greater that you have exceeded the shell's command name limit.

Within the BAT file, the CMD.EXE program is reading the lines, not Tomcat.  Tomcat was responsible for launching the CMD.EXE process (with the provided BAT file argument).

Comment: The smallest limit there [appears to be 2048 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The bat file I am calling isn't under my control.  The offending line is a java command to startup the Jython interpreter with the expected classpath, pythonpath, etc.  Strange thing is this only fails when running under a Tomcat environment - servlet calling the bat file.  If I have a regular old Java application calling the bat file then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a limit of tomcat of java. It is a limit of Windows. 
BTW even Unix systems have such kind of limit just it is typically much bigger.

So, to work around the problem do not create so long command line. 
If you cannot modify your bat file create other batch file that runs your unmodifirable file. This second bat file can be created at runtime dynmically somewhere under user temp. Then you can run it and and remove when it is no longer needed.